# TypeError: _append_dispatcher()

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to predict the stock price of Facebook on the 1664th row of the .csv file. I am encountering an error when it comes to appending a np.array. Here's my code:

```
##predicts price of facebook stock for one day
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

##store and show data
df = pd.read_csv (r'fb.csv')


##get and print last row of data
actual_price = df.tail(1)
#print(actual_price)

##prepare and print svr models
##get all of the data except for last row
df = df.head(len(df)-1)

ind = (np.arange((len(df.index))))
df["index"] = ind
##create empty list to store dependent and independent data
# days1 =
days = np.array([])
adj_close_prices = np.array([])

##get the date and adjusted close prices
df_days = df.loc[:, 'index']
df_adj_close = df.loc[:, 'Adj Close']

##create the independent dataset        ### this part to specify
for day in df_days:
    days = np.append(float(day))
```

And the error which keeps occurring is the following:

```
    days = np.append(float(day))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in append
TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

I have very basic level of Python knowledge and have been using YouTube and online resources to come up with what I have already.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your whole code, but the append problem isn't too hard to fix. Check out [numpy.append()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) documentation and you will notice that it takes 2 parameters that are required (and a third that is optional), in a form of `numpy.append(array_to_apend_to, value_to_apend`) so, in your code it should look like `days = np.append(days, float(day))`